# Different layout for login page in yii framework

Tags: frameworks, yii, yii-components, yii-events

I have login page that i want to call after index.but login and index have same layout.

My requirement is that when i run `locathost/demo/index.php` all tha login and other related pages display on same index.php layout.But i want to run only single `login.php` using yii framework.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the site controller, under the Login action (*public function actionLogin*) you can specifiy a different layout like so:

```
$this->layout = "mylayout";
```

Obviously the layout needs to exists under *protected/views/layouts*

Comment: same way i have Restore page..if i open a restore page..i want to be a new layout for that Restore.php page...i want to same layout for login and restore page...where to write $this->layout = "mylayout"; in which controller?

Comment: You can add that in whichever controller calls the action to render the restore page, so for example you have an action in the site controller called Restore, you can put it there. If you are happy with my answer to you original question, please click the tick to accept the answer :)

Comment: thanks....friend..i also tick eskimo...since i m new to yii so a lot of questions arise. i have database table client_info(id,first_name,last_name,email,passowrd). when i login in to my site using email and password, on the top right in header section of index/home page ..first_name should display of same user whose email is entered...i:e  Welcom first_name          .. reply me thanks